Unable to serialize/deserialize and traverse objects in Ansible
I'm trying to serialize/deserialize and traverse objects residing in a YAML-structure sent during Ansible provisioning.
I have the following string (dynamic_data.elastic_setup_userenv.spaces below):
spaces:
  admins:
    description: "..."
    color: "..."
    initials: "..."
  team1:
    description: "..."
    color: "..."
    initials: "..."
  team2:
    description: "..."
    color: "..."
    initials: "..."
  team3:
    description: "..."
    color: "..."
    initials: "..."
  team4:
    description: "..."
    color: "..."
    initials: "..."

which is serialized and transferred. On the receiving machine I do the following:
    - name:
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Space {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.description }} ({{ item.value.color }})"
      loop: "{{ lookup( 'ansible.builtin.dict', dynamic_data.elastic_setup_userenv.spaces_yaml | ansible.builtin.from_yaml) }}"

which in turn results in the following exception:
FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: {'key': 'spaces', 

what am I doing wrong here?

Hard to say without knowing anything about spaces_yaml.

If the (simplified) value of the attribute spaces is a string
    dd:
      elastic:
        spaces: |
          admins: {description: d0, color: c0, initials: i0}
          team1: {description: d1, color: c1, initials: i1}
          team2: {description: d2, color: c2, initials: i2}

you can test it
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dd.elastic.spaces | type_debug }}"

gives
  msg: AnsibleUnicode

You can also test the converted structure
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dd.elastic.spaces | from_yaml | type_debug }}"

gives as expected
  msg: dict

There are many options on how to iterate a dictionary. You decided to  use the dict lookup plugin
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', dd.elastic.spaces | from_yaml) }}"

should work as expected. Gives abridged
  msg: |-
    key: admins
    value: {color: c0, description: d0, initials: i0}
  msg: |-
    key: team1
    value: {color: c1, description: d1, initials: i1}
  msg: |-
    key: team2
    value: {color: c2, description: d2, initials: i2}

Simpler options are the filter dict2items
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ dd.elastic.spaces | from_yaml | dict2items }}"

, or archaic with_dict
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item | to_yaml }}"
      with_dict: "{{ dd.elastic.spaces | from_yaml }}"

Both iterations above give the same result.


Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dd:
      elastic:
        spaces: |
          admins: {description: d0, color: c0, initials: i0}
          team1: {description: d1, color: c1, initials: i1}
          team2: {description: d2, color: c2, initials: i2}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dd.elastic.spaces | type_debug }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dd.elastic.spaces | from_yaml | type_debug }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('dict', dd.elastic.spaces | from_yaml) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', dd.elastic.spaces | from_yaml) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ dd.elastic.spaces | from_yaml | dict2items }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item | to_yaml }}"
      with_dict: "{{ dd.elastic.spaces | from_yaml }}"



Two changes needed:

You have to use query instead of lookup to make sure you get a list back. See Ensuring list input for loop: using query rather than lookup
Your expression is returning the top content of your yaml string whereas you want to process the dict under the spaces key. You need to address this as well

All together this gives:
    - name: Get info from yaml                                                                                                             
      ansible.builtin.debug:                                                                                                               
        msg: "Space {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.description }} ({{ item.value.color }})"                                               
      loop: "{{ query( 'ansible.builtin.dict', (dynamic_data.elastic_setup_userenv.spaces_yaml | ansible.builtin.from_yaml).spaces) }}"    


Full playbook to test:
- name: Reproduce and fix
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dynamic_data:
      elastic_setup_userenv:
        spaces_yaml: |-
          spaces:
            admins:
              description: "admins description"
              color: "admins color"
              initials: "AI"
            team1:
              description: "team1 description"
              color: "team1 color"
              initials: "T1"
            team2:
              description: "team2 description"
              color: "team2 color"
              initials: "T2"

  tasks:
    - name: Get info from yaml
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Space {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.description }} ({{ item.value.color }})"
      loop: "{{ query( 'ansible.builtin.dict', (dynamic_data.elastic_setup_userenv.spaces_yaml | ansible.builtin.from_yaml).spaces) }}" 

Giving:
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [Reproduce and fix] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Get info from yaml] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'admins', 'value': {'description': 'admins description', 'color': 'admins color', 'initials': 'AI'}}) => {
    "msg": "Space admins is admins description (admins color)"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'team1', 'value': {'description': 'team1 description', 'color': 'team1 color', 'initials': 'T1'}}) => {
    "msg": "Space team1 is team1 description (team1 color)"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'team2', 'value': {'description': 'team2 description', 'color': 'team2 color', 'initials': 'T2'}}) => {
    "msg": "Space team2 is team2 description (team2 color)"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

